# How to fit turn.js flipbook into parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

How can I fit a turn.js flipbook into a parent div?

I have the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My webpage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/hash.js"></script>

</head>

<body style="overflow: auto;">
    <div id='parent_div' style="width: 800px; overflow: auto;">
        <div class="magazine-viewport">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="magazine">
                 <!-- Next button -->
                 <div ignore="1" class="next-button"></div>
                 <!-- Previous button -->
                 <div ignore="1" class="previous-button"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function loadApp() {

            var flipbook = $('.magazine');

            $('.magazine-viewport').css('position', 'unset');

            // Check if the CSS was already loaded

            if (flipbook.width()==0 || flipbook.height()==0) {
                    setTimeout(loadApp, 10);
                    return;
            }

            // Create the flipbook

            flipbook.turn({

                            // Magazine width

                            width: 922,

                            // Magazine height

                            height: 600,

                            // Duration in millisecond

                            duration: 1000,

                            // Hardware acceleration

                            acceleration: !isChrome(),

                            // Enables gradients

                            gradients: true,

                            // Auto center this flipbook

                            autoCenter: true,

                            // Elevation from the edge of the flipbook when turning a page

                            elevation: 50,

                            // The number of pages

                            pages: 12,

                            // Events

                            when: {
                                    turning: function(event, page, view) {

                                            var book = $(this),
                                            currentPage = book.turn('page'),
                                            pages = book.turn('pages');

                                            // Update the current URI

                                            Hash.go('page/' + page).update();

                                            // Show and hide navigation buttons

                                            disableControls(page);


                                            $('.thumbnails .page-'+currentPage).
                                                    parent().
                                                    removeClass('current');

                                            $('.thumbnails .page-'+page).
                                                    parent().
                                                    addClass('current');



                                    },

                                    turned: function(event, page, view) {

                                            disableControls(page);

                                            $(this).turn('center');

                                            if (page==1) { 
                                                    $(this).turn('peel', 'br');
                                            }

                                    },

                                    missing: function (event, pages) {

                                            // Add pages that aren't in the magazine

                                            for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
                                                    addPage(pages[i], $(this));

                                    }
                            }

            });

            // Zoom.js

            $('.magazine-viewport').zoom({
                    flipbook: $('.magazine'),

                    max: function() { 

                            return largeMagazineWidth()/$('.magazine').width();

                    }, 

                    when: {

                            swipeLeft: function() {

                                    $(this).zoom('flipbook').turn('next');

                            },

                            swipeRight: function() {

                                    $(this).zoom('flipbook').turn('previous');

                            },

                            resize: function(event, scale, page, pageElement) {

                                    if (scale==1)
                                            loadSmallPage(page, pageElement);
                                    else
                                            loadLargePage(page, pageElement);

                            },

                            zoomIn: function () {

                                    $('.thumbnails').hide();
                                    $('.made').hide();
                                    $('.magazine').removeClass('animated').addClass('zoom-in');
                                    $('.zoom-icon').removeClass('zoom-icon-in').addClass('zoom-icon-out');

                                    if (!window.escTip && !$.isTouch) {
                                            escTip = true;

                                            $('<div />', {'class': 'exit-message'}).
                                                    html('<div>Press ESC to exit</div>').
                                                            appendTo($('body')).
                                                            delay(2000).
                                                            animate({opacity:0}, 500, function() {
                                                                    $(this).remove();
                                                            });
                                    }
                            },

                            zoomOut: function () {

                                    $('.exit-message').hide();
                                    $('.thumbnails').fadeIn();
                                    $('.made').fadeIn();
                                    $('.zoom-icon').removeClass('zoom-icon-out').addClass('zoom-icon-in');

                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                            $('.magazine').addClass('animated').removeClass('zoom-in');
                                            resizeViewport();
                                    }, 0);

                            }
                    }
            });

            // Zoom event

            if ($.isTouch)
                    $('.magazine-viewport').bind('zoom.doubleTap', zoomTo);
            else
                    $('.magazine-viewport').bind('zoom.tap', zoomTo);


            // Using arrow keys to turn the page

            $(document).keydown(function(e){

                    var previous = 37, next = 39, esc = 27;

                    switch (e.keyCode) {
                            case previous:

                                    // left arrow
                                    $('.magazine').turn('previous');
                                    e.preventDefault();

                            break;
                            case next:

                                    //right arrow
                                    $('.magazine').turn('next');
                                    e.preventDefault();

                            break;
                            case esc:

                                    $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomOut');    
                                    e.preventDefault();

                            break;
                    }
            });

            // URIs - Format #/page/1 

            Hash.on('^page\/([0-9]*)$', {
                    yep: function(path, parts) {
                            var page = parts[1];

                            if (page!==undefined) {
                                    if ($('.magazine').turn('is'))
                                            $('.magazine').turn('page', page);
                            }

                    },
                    nop: function(path) {

                            if ($('.magazine').turn('is'))
                                    $('.magazine').turn('page', 1);
                    }
            });


            $(window).resize(function() {
                    resizeViewport();
            }).bind('orientationchange', function() {
                    resizeViewport();
            });

            // Events for thumbnails

            $('.thumbnails').click(function(event) {

                    var page;

                    if (event.target && (page=/page-([0-9]+)/.exec($(event.target).attr('class'))) ) {

                            $('.magazine').turn('page', page[1]);
                    }
            });

            $('.thumbnails li').
                    bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {

                            $(this).addClass('thumb-hover');

                    }).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {

                            $(this).removeClass('thumb-hover');

                    });

            if ($.isTouch) {

                    $('.thumbnails').
                            addClass('thumbanils-touch').
                            bind($.mouseEvents.move, function(event) {
                                    event.preventDefault();
                            });

            } else {

                    $('.thumbnails ul').mouseover(function() {

                            $('.thumbnails').addClass('thumbnails-hover');

                    }).mousedown(function() {

                            return false;

                    }).mouseout(function() {

                            $('.thumbnails').removeClass('thumbnails-hover');

                    });

            }


            // Regions

            if ($.isTouch) {
                    $('.magazine').bind('touchstart', regionClick);
            } else {
                    $('.magazine').click(regionClick);
            }

            // Events for the next button

            $('.next-button').bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {

                    $(this).addClass('next-button-hover');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {

                    $(this).removeClass('next-button-hover');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.down, function() {

                    $(this).addClass('next-button-down');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.up, function() {

                    $(this).removeClass('next-button-down');

            }).click(function() {

                    $('.magazine').turn('next');

            });

            // Events for the next button

            $('.previous-button').bind($.mouseEvents.over, function() {

                    $(this).addClass('previous-button-hover');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.out, function() {

                    $(this).removeClass('previous-button-hover');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.down, function() {

                    $(this).addClass('previous-button-down');

            }).bind($.mouseEvents.up, function() {

                    $(this).removeClass('previous-button-down');

            }).click(function() {

                    $('.magazine').turn('previous');

            });


            resizeViewport();

            $('.magazine').addClass('animated');

    }

    // Zoom icon

     $('.zoom-icon').bind('mouseover', function() { 

            if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
                    $(this).addClass('zoom-icon-in-hover');

            if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out'))
                    $(this).addClass('zoom-icon-out-hover');

     }).bind('mouseout', function() { 

             if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
                    $(this).removeClass('zoom-icon-in-hover');

            if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out'))
                    $(this).removeClass('zoom-icon-out-hover');

     }).bind('click', function() {

            if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-in'))
                    $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomIn');
            else if ($(this).hasClass('zoom-icon-out')) 
                    $('.magazine-viewport').zoom('zoomOut');

     });


    // Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

    yepnope({
            test : Modernizr.csstransforms,
            yep: ['/assets/js/turn.js'],
            nope: ['/assets/js/turn.html4.min.js'],
            both: ['/assets/js/zoom.min.js', '/js/magazine.js', '/css/magazine.css'],
            complete: loadApp
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the flipbook should fit in to "parent_div" (800px) and the width that it is taking is the width of the explorer. In this way it centers it at the center of my screen and not the center of the div.

Any help would greatly be appresiated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had a function in /js/magazine.js that was resizing my viewport to the entire window's width.

So I just changed the code:

```
var width = $(window).width();
```

for

```
var width = $('#parent_div').width();
```

And voiala.

PS: This code was gotten entirely from an example of turn.js.

I hope this answer helps other people as future reference.